# I'm trying to match datatable value to combobox to edit data

Tags: javascript, html

I want to edit my datatable value using modals, so it won't have to change the page. I can get the datatable value that I'm looking for, but I have trouble to make my edit form which have combobox value that should be selected with previous data. Can anyone help me with this trouble? Because I'm still newbie in javascript things.

This is what my html look a like.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByName('jo');
console.log(elements.length);
for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
  if (elements[i].text == data[1]) {
    console.log(elements[i]);
    elements[i].change();
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="nj" class="bootstrap-select" name="no_jo" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%">
  <option name="jo" value="1"> 190001</option>
  <option name="jo" value="2"> 190002</option>
  <option name="jo" value="4"> 190003</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you provide an mininmal reproduceable example?

Comment: Please provide a sample  of your`data` array as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes:

1. Added `data` to leverage some array to match elements with.
2. Removed the use of [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) which used jQuery and it was not being handled properly, by HTML's [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) instead

```js
var dropDown = document.getElementById('nj'),
    elements = document.getElementsByName('jo'),
    data = ['abcd', '190002']; // <- added this which was missing, modify as you need

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].text == data[i]) {
    console.log(i, elements[i].text, data[i]);
    dropDown.selectedIndex = i;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="nj" class="bootstrap-select" name="no_jo" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%">
  <option name="jo" value="1"> 190001</option>
  <option name="jo" value="2"> 190002</option>
  <option name="jo" value="4"> 190003</option>
</select>
```